# Migrating to prepared statements

Tags: php, prepared-statement, fetch

I know that there are similar topics to this but they didn't helped me out, I want to migrate my code to prepared statements but I keep on getting errors or wrong answers. The plan is to get code like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM our_videos ORDER BY datemade DESC LIMIT 10";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $id             = $row["id"];
    $title          = $row["title"];
    $description    = $row["description"];
    echo "this is first row id".$id."";
}
```

To something like this(It's wrong example that I'm currently working on):

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, "SELECT id,title,description,champion FROM our_videos WHERE datemade BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL ? DAY AND NOW() AND LENGTH(champion) - LENGTH(REPLACE(champion, '$', '')) =? ORDER BY ? LIMIT 10");
$filter_date           = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['filter_by_date']);
$filter_arrangement    = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['filter_by_arrangement']);
$filter_champion_count = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['filter_by_champion_count']);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iis', $filter_date, $filter_champion_count, $filter_arrangement);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo 'My name is '.$data['id'].'and my email is <br/>';
}
$res = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $single_id, $single_title, $single_description, $single_champion);
```

And I'm getting this error trying to do the example above:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in
>   /home/troll4lol/domains/troll4lol.com/public_html/other_videos.php on
>   line 12

I'm really confused about this whole prepared statements thing, it looked like it's not going to be hard but it's...

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` when using prepared statements.

Comment: Where do you set `$res`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done some changes to your code according to the example in the docs
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

One great thing about parameterized queries is that we no longer (usually) need to escape data, it's done for us :D

```
$sql = "SELECT id,title,description,champion
        FROM our_videos
        WHERE datemade BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL ? DAY AND NOW()
        AND LENGTH(champion) - LENGTH(REPLACE(champion, '$', '')) =?
        ORDER BY # // :(
        LIMIT 10";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, $sql);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iis', $_POST['filter_by_date'], $_POST['filter_by_champion_count'], $_POST['filter_by_arrangement']);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $single_id, $single_title, $single_description, $single_champion);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    echo $single_id . ' ' . $single_title . ' ' . $single_description . ' ' . $single_champion;
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Note the sad face though, you can only bind data with placeholders. Column/table names are part of the schema and cannot be bound.

Comment: So what should I do if ORDER BY can be 6 different variants?

Comment: @Donny123 validate that the submitted order by is valid / in your whitelist and insert it directly into the query string

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works well, but I'll need to study it to understand how this whole prepare statement stuff works, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `mysqli_fetch_array`, because you're using `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` to set the variables when you fetch.

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $single_id, $single_title, $single_description, $single_champion);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    echo "My name is $single_id and my email is <br>";
}
```

See the examples in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).